# Divisibility of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Can anyone explain this? I'm new to this topic.
Prove that for all integers a, b, c , if a | c and b | c , then ab | c² .

Comment: Hint:as $a|c,b|c$, $c=ak,c=bm$ can you proceed

Answer (score 1):

That implies $c=ak$ and $c=bq$ so multiplying the EQ we get $c^2=ab(Kq)$ therefore $ab|c^2$